# position:sticky - not sticky when it reaches the footer

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky

I have a parent container. The parent container is having 2 children with a sticky header and a footer.
The issue is that when the user scrolls and reaches the footer area, the sticky header's position changes, i.e it goes up along with the other scrollable contents. I have created a fiddle for the demo.
https://jsfiddle.net/d653wrxb/

```
<div>
   <div>
    <div class="sticky">Sticky Header</div>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

```
footer {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    height: 500px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
    top: 56px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Is there any way to stick the header even if it reaches the bottom. 
Note: I cannot use position: absolute as it breaks all the children inside the main content area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky elements are visible only within the dimensions of the parent. As your parent div is going out of viewport, the sticky element is also moving out. Move the sticky div to the outer div.

```
<div>
  <div class="sticky">Sticky Header</div>
  <div>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
    <p>Dummy text to cause scrollbars</p>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qs5vfjL0/

Comment: Hmm. I agree. but for some reason, I cannot move the div oustside. I am using ReactJS and the component structure cannot be modified at this point of time. I was looking if something can be done in this particular case. Anyways, thanks :)

Comment: If you can add React code snippet, I can see if something can be done.